# Чем можно заменить метод Strings.Space()

Tags: c#, методы

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите чем можно заменить метод `Strings.Space();` ?

Имеется кусок кода:

```
foreach (var inject in GetChild(foregroundWindow))
{
  var GameFX = Strings.Space(200);
  var startIndex = GetClassName((int)inject, ref GameFX, 200);
  pClassName = GameFX.Remove(startIndex, 200 - startIndex);
  if (GameFX.ToLower() == "listview")
  {
    list.Add(inject);
  }
  if ((GameFX.ToLower() == "public") | (GameFX.ToLower() == "directuihwnd"))
  {
     num4++;
  }
}
```

Не хочу использовать VisualBasic в таких случаях), чем можно заменить?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617486/is-there-a-spacen-method-in-c-net

Comment: @Ev_Hyper: Почему не как ответ?

Comment: @VladD, не знаю :) спасибо, оформил как ответ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете использовать специальный конструктор для [`String(char c, int count)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xsa4321w(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var GameFX = new string(' ', 200);
```